# Two clients write on server and another client read from it with socket in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I'm new in socket programming.
My program creates two clients that write to a server, this server reads data using threads and then prints them. I would like to send all this data to another client when it makes a request. Have I to create another socket or is it possible to use the same used before? 
Here is my code.
Thanks.

Server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close
#include<pthread.h>

struct message {  //dichiarazione struct
  time_t timestamp;  
  char g;  //process identifier
  int x;
};

struct message client_message[10000];
int q=0;

static void * socketThread(void *arg)
{
  int newSocket = *((int *)arg);

  while(read(newSocket , &client_message[q] , sizeof(client_message))!=0) {
    printf("message %d  %d %ld\n",client_message[q].x,client_message[q].g,client_message[q].timestamp);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    q++;
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
  int serverSocket, newSocket;
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size;

  //Create the socket. 

  serverSocket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  // Configure settings of the server address struct

  // Address family = Internet 

  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_UNIX;

  //Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order 

  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(55555);

  //Set IP address to localhost 

  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
//INADDR_ANY;

  //Set all bits of the padding field to 0 

  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

  //Bind the address struct to the socket 

  bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

  //Listen on the socket, with 40 max connection requests queued 

  if(listen(serverSocket,50)==0)
    printf("Listening\n");

  else
    printf("Error\n");

    pthread_t tid[2];
    int i = 0;

  while(i<2)
  {

    //Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection

    addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;

    newSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);

    //for each client request creates a thread and assign the client request to it to process

    //so the main thread can entertain next request

    if( pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, socketThread, &newSocket) != 0 )
      printf("Failed to create thread\n"); 

    i++;
  }

  pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
  pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);

  for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    printf("%d aaa %d\n",client_message[i].x,client_message[i].g); 
  }

  close(newSocket);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this something like a chat? You want other connected clients to receive the most recent message?

Comment: @pbn the 2 clients write an array of struct message to the server and the third client reads all the messages from the server

Comment: You're creating a Unix domain socket, but then populating and binding an ipv4 `sockaddr_in` struct instead of a `sockaddr_un`... Is that code you posted somehow actually working?

Comment: Your call to `read` throws away the returned value, which is the number of bytes read. There is no other way to know how many bytes you read. If you read only the `timestamp` and not `g` or `x`, your code will have no idea and happily process the partial message. Stream sockets provides streams of bytes, not messages.

Comment: I see at least two ways this can be achieved. Either you introduce some form of higher level messaging in which you differentiate between publishers and subscribers , e.g. user at the beginning sends you an identifying message "SUBSCRIBE" or "PUBLISH", you save the socket to subscribers/publishers array and send all subscribers message that from publishers. The other way is opening a second port and differentiate publishers/subscribers based on port they are attached to.

Comment: Is this a toy / educational project? If not, did you consider using [facil.io](http://facil.io) (I'm biased)? It includes a pub/sub API that allows you to achieve what you're trying to do.